# Great idea for embedded development

Tags: user-interface, embedded

For my university I (and three others), are searching for a project that utilizes at least one embedded device, web services or other web technology, and a Graphical User Interface.

Currently we are looking at developing a unified remote, that is an extendable application on a cell phone through which you can control your media center. Any ideas, or advice on this will be appreciated, though it is not the focus of this question.

We are having a hard time finding interesting (or funny) projects on which we can work a complete semester. Any ideas will be greatly appreciated. The software will be released as free software. (GPL or BSD license).

We all have a Bsc in Software Engineering.

EDIT: I am very pleased with the suggestions so far. Thanks to everyone, and keep it coming.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about follower: carry a device, as you move from room to room in your house devices configure themselves to your preference - lights, music etc. If two people are in the room some precedence rules.

Is that possible just on the presence of a mobile phone?

Comment: I like the idea of that. Implemented with something like RFID would be somewhat simple. However, a research group at my university is developing some thingy that does that. Colliding with their work is not encouraged.

Answer (score 3):

Another idea (from the top of my head):

A work environment ensurance thing. We programmers like to develop in nice and quiet environments. Unfortunately some people tends to annoy us with their disturbing behaviour (or just by being loud).

So the project could be to create devices wich tracks the stress level (sweat levels, pulse etc.) of the individual and their impact onto others.

An example: One individual is very loud (the device should measure this), and others around him becomes stressed and/or unfocused because of this. The serverside sw, should then detect and warn him to quit down a bit to improve the work environment.

Comments?

Comment: +1 yes please, real research to back up our need for a good place to work.

Answer (score 1):

What do you peeps like doing?  Build an app for it.

So, if you like drinking coffee build a application which will find the nearest frothy coffee shoppe (or if you're particular, the nearest Peets/Starbucks/Whatever-ocino).  This idea works for beer too.

If you buy stuff off e-Bay build a sniper app.

If you enjoy playing frisbee build an app which locates your nearest friends and sends them a text asking whether they want to goof off lectures and go to the park.

Heck, you could even build an app which monitors your SO questions and alerts you when you get an answer (although I don't know whether the [data services SO currently offer will be up to the job](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7312/is-there-a-guide-to-accessing-stackoverflow-data-programmatically)).

Answer (score 1):

The standout companies that have made great universal (programmable) remotes are : logitech, and philips.

One of the big problems with these types of devices is the ability of the general consumer to actually program all of their various devices.  Logitech has done an outstanding job of providing a fairly simple Web based user setup experience that then implements a very usable universal control.

I would definitely look at what they have done for some ideas on universal remote controls.

Comment: Very nice advice indeed! We will most certainly look into this.

Answer (score 1):

How about an app and hardware that will tell me when my wife's plants need watering? (It's somehow my fault if they don't get watered.)

Answer (score 1):

OK then: the recipe generating fridge. Rfid tags on the contents know what's available and the expiry dates. The database knows the recipes. The fridge emails/texts you to say "buy some mushrooms and you can have a delicous ham and mushroom omelette while the eggs are still fresh."

Comment: That would actually be quite difficult to do right i think. Not the tagging stuff which is somewhat easy, but the amount thing would be non-trivial to do without incuring too much overhead for the user. (The casual user, like me, likes to pick ice cream from the fridge witout updating the amount ;)

Comment: Ah, but the fridge weighs things when they're put back. (Just like the self service scales at the supermarket, they detect if what you scanned matches the increased weight in your bag). So the detecter notes waht item was renmoved and hence caclulates what was put back when you put it back.

Answer (score 1):

Benjamin and all those aspiring to do embedded projects ...

When you start a project, especially in embedded systems, you need to understand that the hardware is **not** your PC but some special device. And every sensor will be a transducer in itself. The **only thing** that would matter to students is that **everything costs and are costly**

So, it will be good to make sure that the idea is such that,

1. It can be **completed** by the
   **project members** within the given **timeframe**
2. All the required **development
   tools** like **hardware etc** can be
   **really bought**
3. Of all, it good to ensure that the
   project enables you to learn
   something **useful for your career** ...

To do all this it is better set some **achievable goals**

Answer (score 0):

Develop a system in which you can program the lighting system of your house. You can set up their schedule one time and everything should work automatically.

Comment: Unfortunately, the embedded requirement is somewhat unsatisfied (because the interface to switch light on/off is too simple)

Answer (score 0):

I really love working witht the Atmel ststk1000/stk1006/stk1002 development boards for tht AVR32. [ATSTK1000](http://www.atmel.com/dyn/products/tools_card.asp?tool_id=3918)

2x Ethernet
QVGA lcd
USB 2.0
SD/MMC
Conpact flash
Supported embedded linux
IR
Audio
ps2 interfaces
uarts
++
familiy atmel page:
[AVR 32 family home](http://www.atmel.com/products/AVR32/)
online forums
[Forums for CPU](http://www.avrfreaks.net/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=index&c=5)